# htaccess with/without slash before file name

Tags: .htaccess

**FOLDER STRUCTURE:**

```
root/.htaccess
root/dont-index-me.php
```

As you can see above, htaccess file and dont-index-me.php are in same folder so which one is correct content for htaccess file?

**WITH SLASH:**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /dont-index-me.php
```

**WITHOUT SLASH:**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: dont-index-me.php
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WITHOUT SLASH:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: dont-index-me.php
```